# TLS version passed by jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am doing **performance testing of an e-commerce website**,in which I need to

pass through **PayPal** gateway.I want to know which **TLS version** is my jmeter passing.

Here is my **SSL configuration** of **jmeter.properties** file

```
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # SSL configuration
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ## SSL System properties are now in system.properties

    # JMeter no longer converts javax.xxx property entries in this file into System properties.
    # These must now be defined in the system.properties file or on the command-line.
    # The system.properties file gives more flexibility.

    # By default, SSL session contexts are now created per-thread, rather than being shared.
    # The original behaviour can be enabled by setting the JMeter property to true
    #https.sessioncontext.shared=false

    # Be aware that https default protocol may vary depending on the version of JVM
    # See https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https
    # See https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58236
    # Default HTTPS protocol level:
    #https.default.protocol=TLS
    # This may need to be changed here (or in user.properties) to:
    #https.default.protocol=SSLv3

    # List of protocols to enable. You may have to select only a subset if you find issues with target server.
    # This is needed when server does not support Socket version negotiation, this can lead to:
    # javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    # java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    # see https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54759
    #https.socket.protocols=SSLv2Hello SSLv3 TLSv1

    # Control if we allow reuse of cached SSL context between iterations
    # set the value to 'false' to reset the SSL context each iteration
    #https.use.cached.ssl.context=true

    # Start and end index to be used with keystores with many entries
    # The default is to use entry 0, i.e. the first
    #https.keyStoreStartIndex=0
    #https.keyStoreEndIndex=0

       #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Test Script Recorder miscellaneous configuration
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Whether to attempt disabling of samples that resulted from redirects
    # where the generated samples use auto-redirection
    #proxy.redirect.disabling=true

    # SSL configuration
    #proxy.ssl.protocol=TLS
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have not changed default settings my expectation is that JMeter should be using `TLS` protocol in general and `TLSv1.2` in particular. If this doesn't match your payment gateway configuration you can amend `https.socket.protocols` according to what your application expects.

[image: JMeter SSL Debug]

In order to get debugging output for SSL and network stuff you can add the next lines to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.util.HttpSSLProtocolSocketFactory" level="debug" />
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.util.JsseSSLManager" level="debug" />
<Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
<Logger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="debug" />
```

and the following line to *system.properties* file:

```
javax.net.debug=all
```

**JMeter restart will be required to pick up the changes**

More information:

- [Debugging SSL/TLS Connections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html)
- [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging)
- [Enabling Debug Logging](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging)

Comment: This is my jmeter log  **2018-08-01 22:21:04,883 DEBUG o.a.j.u.JsseSSLManager: Using threadLocal SSL context for: Thread Group 1-1
2018-08-01 22:21:08,956 DEBUG o.a.h.c.p.RequestAddCookies: CookieSpec selected: ignoreCookies**

This is my console log  **Thread Group 1-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 26**

Comment: I might be wrong but looking into your response I can guess that JMeter is using **TLSv1.2**

Comment: how do you pass these things to jmeter when running from command line?

Comment: Why you're hijacking 3-years-old thread with unrelated question instead of asking a new one? As exception: for logging - use `-L` command-line argument, for `java.net.debug` - `-D` command-line argument like: `jmeter -Lorg.apache.http=DEBUG -Lorg.apache.jmeter.util.HttpSSLProtocolSocketFactory=DEBUG -Lorg.apache.jmeter.util.JsseSSLManager=DEBUG -Djavax.net.debug=all`. More information: [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) and [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

Answer (score 0):

add this line to user.properties

```
https.default.protocol=TLSv1.2
```